# How the batch size is determined in snowflake python connector

Tags: snowflake-connector

When using snowflake python connector, it can return batches of result sets. How the batch size is determined?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about `fetch_pandas_batches` it is determined by the size of the result set of your query and it can't be settable for now.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/320#issuecomment-641706112